# Canvas 2D game framework

Tags: html, canvas

This is more like investigation rather then question.

I would like to receive your suggestions regarding framework I should chose to fulfill following needs:

1. Quick rendering objects in 2D game
2. Engine for objects interacting(bullet hit unit) built in
3. Ability to work with data received with websockes

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question will likely be considered off-topic, but I suggest you take a look at http://phaser.io/
For the Websockets-Part check out http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/6256-simple-phaser-websocket-guide/

Comment: Thank you. I willl take your links to consideration

Comment: @AlexanderCapone. Asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stackoverflow. You should delete your question. ;-)

Comment: @markE Of course, will do. Let's agree to keep it for 1-2 days more, to get maybe some more suggestions :) if there is someone eager to help me with investigations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

With Visual js you can setup page like this.

This is ***ONPAGE-EDITOR*** , good for visual view . run from cmd for linux users
server/node editor.js also for windows cmd . See video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVp-JsAha94&feature=youtu.be

You will get :

```
99% canvas 2d
Add new object
Create webcam component
Create coallision (basic - rect)
Create textBox (virtual keyboard)
Create particle ( works with animation component)
Atach player (basic movement)
localStarage
MultiPeer ( share your object in real time)
```

**Tools** (windows gui):

**Visual-JS GE beta 1**

comes with visual editor , good for coding .
[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxUBPDhB-3I)

Implemented :

- quick code insert
- source code editor
- run for test (chrome,firefox,opera) In new update safari for win also will be implemented.
- Add new game object , you can select image set from drop down list ...

[image]

**-Encode scripts** this tool use *javascriptobfuscator.com* API
**-makeLib** (put all script from lib to build.js - need to load run.js     manual)
**-Multilaguage** easy win gui for input labels (i will post explanation)

You can desing on web page your objects.
App created from visual js always work on all browsers .

- Networking implemented
  ( video chat , object share )

last updates :

- [virtual keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hy833-hOxS4)

Test VK at : [Last update link - visula-js](http://maximumroulette.com/visual-js)

-peertopeer video chat (signaling node.js)

this will help you for object share :[Object share - position](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL5GGAoBDSk)

account system basic with node.js

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visualjs

Implemented real time multiplayer for platformer type of game:

https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/visual-ts-game-engine

**Next updates :**

Download :

[Download Link nightly build - git](https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js)